# How do I add code snippets within quotes for Asp.net? (I.e.: <div id="my@model.id">)

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to have custom id names, depending on the id of the current model I'm iterating through.

for example:

```
<div id="my@model.id">
```

..... 
I thought good old fashioned <%# %> would work, but it doesn't....

Anybody help?

Comment: Try some parenthesis `<div id="my@(model.id)">`?

Comment: why not use custom attributes instead of id?

Comment: Thanks, parenthesis did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can add parenthesis as below

```
<div id="my@(model.id)">
```

or you can add an additional property to your model class. Let's say it's named `CustomID` and assume `id` is an int

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    // .... your other properties

    public string CustomID
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("my{0}", this.id);
        }
    }
}
```

Use `CustomID` property in your view as below

```
<div id="@model.CustomID">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parenthesis. Example:

```
<div id="my@(model.id)">
```